# Wordpress memory limit

Tags: wordpress, plugins, memory-management

I am having only 180 posts on my site. 200 visitors per day. Still facing fatal error: out of memory issues when i visit some admin page or when i edit/add post.

I can increase the memory limit through wp-config.php. But, would it be a permanent solution? If the problem can be occurred on so less posts and visitors then it will really arise when posts would be increased.

> Can any one tell/suggest which hosting
>   plan would be suitable to host
>   wordpress blogs?
>
> Or any plugin like runtime memory
>   manager so that i can host my blog on
>   any server?
>
> Or some tips so that i can minimize
>   the memory usage?

I already had deactivated most of the plugins. using gzip response, using wp super cache, optimizing DB on weekly basis, and planning to write short posts

Memory Limit    64 MB

Comment: What is your current memory limit?

Comment: It's unlikely you're hitting the memory limit because of any core processes. What pages give you trouble? Are you running any global plugins?

Comment: I face problem when i visit plugin page. Or when i add/edit a post

Comment: 64 MB should be more than enough. I'm betting it's one of your plugins. What plugins are you using?

Comment: I hadn't added any plugin from last 2 months. But facing problem from last 2 days. however, how can i determine it?

Comment: @articlestack the only reliable method is deactivating them one by one, and trying out whether it still happens. It's odd though if nothing has changed. Could it be that the web host reduced the limit recently?

Answer (score 0):

Add to wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT' , '512M' );
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT' , '512M' );
```

Answer (score 0):

paste this code in wp-config.php file just before the line that says ‘That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging.’

define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );